# How to create the below JSON Object Structure in Java

Tags: java, android

Below is the json object structure which I want to create.

```
{
        "userInfo": {
            "email": "a@a.com",
            "full_name": "Niraj Rajbhandari",
            "password": "buddhanagar",
            "business_category_id": "0",
            "user_type": "0"
        },
        "businessAddress": {
            "street1": "Shram Marg",
            "state": "Bagmati",
            "zip": "0234",
            "phone1": "3458364853",
            "country": "nepal"
        },
        "companyInfo": {
            "name": "Test",
            "vat_date": "2015-05-06",
            "vat_status": "0",
            "registration_number": "1"
        }
    }
```

Below are the my codes.

```
    public class RegistrationModel {
        public List<UserInfo> userInfo;
        public   List<BusinessModel> businessAddress;
        public List<CompanyInfoModel> companyInfo;
    }

    public class Tax
    {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
        RegistrationModel registrationModel = new RegistrationModel();
     // User list data
                    registrationModel.userInfo = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
                    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
                    userInfo.setEmail(personinfo.get(0).getEmail());
                    userInfo.setFull_name(personinfo.get(0).getFull_name());
                    userInfo.setPassword(personinfo.get(0).getPassword());
                    userInfo.setBusiness_category_id(personinfo.get(0).getBusiness_category_id());
                    userInfo.setUser_type(personinfo.get(0).getUser_type());
                    registrationModel.userInfo.add(userInfo);

                    // Business Address

                    registrationModel.businessAddress = new ArrayList<BusinessModel>();
                    BusinessModel businessModel = new BusinessModel();
                    businessModel.setStreet1(businessModels.get(0).getStreet1());
                    businessModel.setState(businessModels.get(0).getState());
                    businessModel.setZip(businessModels.get(0).getZip());
                    businessModel.setPhone1(businessModels.get(0).getPhone1());
                    businessModel.setCountry(businessModels.get(0).getCountry());
                    registrationModel.businessAddress.add(businessModel);

                    // Company Data
                    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    //get current date time with Date()
                    Date date = new Date();

                    registrationModel.companyInfo = new ArrayList<CompanyInfoModel>();
                    CompanyInfoModel companyInfoModel = new CompanyInfoModel();
                    companyInfoModel.setName(businessModels.get(0).getCompany_Name());
                    companyInfoModel.setVat_date(dateFormat.format(date));
                    companyInfoModel.setVat_status(0);
                    companyInfoModel.setRegistration_number(Hmrc_reg_no.getText().toString());
                    registrationModel.companyInfo.add(companyInfoModel);

gson.toJson(registrationModel)

    }
```

the above code generate the below structure

```
{
    "userInfo": [{
        "email": "a@a.com",
        "full_name": "Niraj Rajbhandari",
        "password": "buddhanagar",
        "business_category_id": "0",
        "user_type": "0"
    }],
    "companyInfo": [{
        "name": "Test",
        "vat_date": "2015-05-06",
        "vat_status": "0",
        "registration_number": "1"
    }],"businessAddress": [{
        "street1": "Shram Marg",
        "state": "Bagmati",
        "zip": "0234",
        "phone1": "3458364853",
        "country": "nepal"
    }]

}
```

Can anyone please give me a code to create the json object strucure in JAVA. In the above code I don't want []bracket . I want the above mention structure

Comment: have you tried [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) it's one of the easiest and powerful library.

Comment: public List<UserInfo> userInfo; change it to public UserInfo userInfo because gson converts the list into JsonArray

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
JSONObject o1=new JSONObject("userInfo");
    o1.put("email","a@a.com");
    o1.put(...);

    JSONObject o2=new JSONObject("businessAddress");
    o2.put("street1","shram Marg");
    o2.put(...);

    JSONObject o3=new JSONObject("companyInfo");
    o3.put("name","Test");
    o3.put(...);

    JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
    array.put(o1);
    array.put(o2);
    array.put(o3);
```

Comment: This code will generate the [] bracket in json structure. I don't want to generate the [] bracket.How , can i do that??

Answer (score 0):

change your RegistrationModel to this

```
public class RegistrationModel {
    public UserInfo userInfo;
    public BusinessModel businessAddress;
    public CompanyInfoModel companyInfo;
}
```

and then

```
registrationModel.userInfo = new UserInfo(); //remove this line
.....
   your code
.....
registrationModel.userInfo=userInfo;
```

and same for rest 2 objects also